# VBA Code for Conditional Visibility

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im currently working on a form in MS Access 2013 and have a button to switch between two data modes, Read Only and Edit. I have a label saying "Edit Mode" and Im trying to display it only when the data mode is Edit. With that in mind, and the fact that Im extremely new to coding/programming as a whole, here is my code behind the button:

```
If Me.AllowEdits = True Then
    DoCmd.close acForm, "frmStudents"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStudents", acNormal, "", "", acReadOnly, acNormal
    Me.txtBox.Visible = False

ElseIf Me.AllowEdits = False Then
    DoCmd.close acForm, "frmStudents"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStudents", acNormal, "", "", acFormEdit, acNormal
    Me.txtBox.Visible = True

End If
```

I keep getting an error saying that the object is closed or doesnt exist when I use the button.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to close a form that is not open?  It also looks like you have you logic back to front on the open form

Comment: Why do you need to close and then open the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs in the same form you close and then re-open? If so:

1) the instance of the form will be close, 
2) You open a second instance of the form, 
3) The last statement  (`Me.Textbox.visible = true`) run in the instance of the form that is...closed and that's throws the error.

By the way your code has no real effect: You can Hide or Show your Textbox with just 1 line of code:

```
   Me.TextBox.visible = not Me.Allowedits
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help <3